# How to refresh particular tab of rich tabpanel?

Tags: jsf, richfaces, tabpanel

I have `rich:tabPanel` with `switchtype` as client.

When i did page refresh in 3rd tab its navigating to first tab. Please find the code snippet below.

Please suggest how to refresh only recall tab.

Also if I use switch type as server or ajax, command button in recall tab will not work, for commandbutton to action need to click twice or triple.

```
<rich:tabPanel id="meainmenu1" width="80%" styleClass="panelGrid_class" switchType="client" rendered="true">
    <rich:tab id="menu1" label="Display / Delete" style="font-weight:bold;font-size:15px">
        some code here
    </rich:tab>
    <rich:tab id="menu2" label="Add / Modify">
        some code here
    </rich:tab>
    <rich:tab id="menu3" label="Zoom" rendered="#{not mcifTransMBean.consoleBasedTrans}">
    </rich:tab>
    <rich:tab id="menu4" label="Benf. View" rendered="#{not mcifTransMBean.consoleBasedTrans}">
    </rich:tab>
    <rich:tab id="menu5" label="Recall" >
        <ui:include src="/pages/mctrans/reCallMcifTrans.xhtml" />           
    </rich:tab>
```

Comment: I did not try but reRendering as "meainMenu1:menu2" shuld work. Did you try sth like this?

Comment: Your actual problem could either be that you have nested `<h:form/>`s or you just need to place an `<h:form/>` in individual tabs and you'll still be able to use `switchType="ajax"`.